# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: profile.map is not a function in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the above error every time I try fetching data from a third-party API source(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50`) using Axios. The problem seems to be with the `profile.map()` function because when I console.log the response received from Axios, it displays all the data. You would find the `profile.map()` function on the `list.jsx` element right at the start of return. I have seen the previous solutions and am pretty sure that I have done almost everything that was suggested in those. Here's the code:

screen.jsx displays the list:

```
import "./screen.css";
import Header from "../header/header";
import List from "../list/list";

const Screen = () => {
    return (
        <div className="mainScreen">
            <Header></Header>
            <List></List>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Screen;
```

list.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./list.css";

const List = () => {
    const [profile, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50").then(
            res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                setData(res.data);
                console.log(profile);
            }
        )
    });

    return (
        <div className="main">
            {/*This is where the error gets thrown*/}
            {profile.map((key, value) => <div className="listCard">
                <div className="userName">
                    <div style={{ margin: "10px 0 10px 20px" }}>Username : {profile[value].login.username}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="details">
                    <div className="topDetails">
                        <div className="nameAndEmail">
                            <div style={{ fontSize: "25px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Mr Siddhartha Chatterjee</div>
                            <div style={{ fontSize: "20px", color: "rgb(128, 128, 112)", marginTop: "20px" }}>Email: siddc.8@gmail.com</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="picture">
                            <div className="imageBox"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="bottomDetails">
                        <div className="nationality">
                            <div style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "22px" }}>User for 6 years</div>
                            <div style={{ fontSize: "20px", marginBottom: "8px" }}>Age: 25</div>
                            <div style={{ fontSize: "20px", marginBottom: "8px" }}>Nationality: Indian</div>
                            <div style={{ fontSize: "18px", marginBottom: "8px" }}>#: 9073030038</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="address">
                            <div style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: "18px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Address:</div>
                            <div>48, Tarun Sengupta Sarani,</div>
                            <div>Dum Dum, Kolkata, West Bengal, India</div>
                            <div>700079</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )};
        </div>
    );
}

export default List;
```

The error :

```
list.jsx:19 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: profile.map is not a function
    at List (list.jsx:19)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21893)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:16139)
    at list.jsx:12
```

Comment: use profile.results.map instead of profile.map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the results the API returned? It returns something that looks like this

```json
{
    "results": [...],
    "info": {
        "seed": "574cecafce235b8c",
        "results": 50,
        "page": 1,
        "version": "1.3"
    }
}
```

Since you are doing `profile.map`, I am assuming that `profile` should be a list. `res.data` returned from the API is an object with properties `results` and `info`, where `results` is probably the data you're looking for. To fix your error, you should pass `res.data.results` into the `setData` function instead of `res.data`

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50").then(
        res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            setData(res.data.results);
            console.log(profile);
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton. Now I see where I went wrong

Comment: No problem, just mark this as the correct answer